# Smart idea to buy the woks that Chinese restaurant chefs use, for my home's electric induction cook top?

Tags: equipment, wok

I need a non stick wok for my [Frigidaire electric induction cook top](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1154534). What do you think of the the copycat technique?  Why don't I just buy the type of wok used by Chinese restaurant chefs?

1. But what type of wok do Chinese restaurants use? [Carbon steel](https://robbreport.com/food-drink/dining/review-why-michelin-star-kitchens-use-made-in-carbon-steel-pans-2889498/)? [Cast iron](https://thewoksoflife.com/best-wok-to-buy/)?
2. How often do these chefs season their woks? But will this work for me at home?  I've never seasoned a wok before! I'm afraid I can't maintain and preserve these woks like these Cantonese restaurant chefs can. What if I don't have enough time to season?

[image]

Comment: Woks used by commercial chefs will not be non-stick, and they do not use induction hobs. Induction is difficult to use with a wok because of the curved bottom, so your priority should be making sure what you buy actually be usable on your cook top.

Comment: "Woks used by commercial chefs will not be non-stick". Can you elaborate pls? Then won't food stick to these Chinese restaurants' woks? I watched Youtube videos of these Chinese restaurant chefs using these woks, and no food stuck to their woks!

Comment: "non-stick" is defined as a coating provided by the manufacturer - used to always be 'teflon' but newer, more durable surface coatings are now available. "Non-stick" doesn't actually relate to how 'sticky' the surface is. A well-used, well-seasoned wok will be just as "not sticky" as a 'non-stick' wok...

Comment: 'Non-stick' refers to a specific chemical coating (see my answer here for example: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/115427/are-all-stainless-pans-necessarily-non-stick/115429#115429). At the high temperatures used in a commercial Chinese kitchen the non-stick coating would degrade. A competent cook can make sure food does not stick through various methods (using oil, moving it around regularly, controlling the temperature etc.) and a well-seasoned pan will also help with this. (Note that seasoning is only done for bare metal, not for non-stick surfaces.)

Comment: There's no point in buying a wok if you don't have a gas stove with pretty high heat. Chinese stir-fry is all about the flames. Just buy a large pan, preferably non-stick. And don't really expect your stir-fry would be as good as one cooked on a gas stove...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't buy a wok like a Chinese restaurant uses because you can't use a round-bottom wok on an induction hob.
You can buy induction hobs specifically for woks, but they're a bit specialist, as are those colossal burners in the picture above.

Generally speaking, for a wok you want as much of it heated as possible. Induction [or any electric hob] will only ever heat the flat surface in contact with the ring. Domestic gas is better, & you can tilt the wok to aid ingredient distribution rather than having to leave it flat on the ring all the time.
Home-cooked Chinese-style food must necessarily adopt a different technique because you simply cannot generate the same amount of heat as a commercial kitchen.

If you don't have time/skill/patience to season a wok & keep it seasoned, then get a non-stick. Just don't get a cheap one, or it will peel off in three months.

My own wok is one of these - [Masterclass](https://www.masterclass.co/cookware-1/frying-pans-woks/carbon-steel-35-5cm-wok-mccwok3.htm) - and has withstood everything I can throw at it for over two years, without showing *any* sign of scratching, burning, evaporating or anything else detrimental to the surface. I treat it with little respect, though I only use wooden or plastic utensils for all my pans, & wash it in regular washing-up liquid (dish soap) with the same brush I use for everything else. The outside is scuffed & scratched, but the inside still looks as new.
And it only cost 30 quid [bucks/euros].

When you're throwing food around in this, you will quickly realise why you don't want a cast iron one… the weight.

Comment: Experienced Chinese cooks (amateur or professional) generally prefer cast iron because it retains heat better. But yes, weight is a concern, although I guess I'm just used to it...